# Count in sql with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have table temp which contain 4 column 
as

```
create table Temp
(
seqno int identity (1,1),
name varchar(20),
towncd numeric,
Counttown_cd,

)
```

i want write Query where it return count of town but if name and towncd is same 
then count shroud added in previous record
like

```
1 man   0001 
2 man   0001 
3 test  0003 
4 man   0001  
5 man   0001
```

it shoud return 
as

```
    1 man  0001 2
    2 man  0001 null
    3 test 0003 1
    4 man  0001 2
    5 man  0001 null
```

i have try following Query :

```
    SELECT p.seqno ,p.name,P.towncd ,COUNT(P.towncd )Counttown_cd
                FROM temp P
                GROUP BY P.name,P.towncd ,p.seqno 
                order by p.seqno
```

Comment: the output for 3 test 0003  should be  1 or 2?

Comment: @etsa 1 it just dummy data i try to create  we need to count no of town cd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your edit to your question added a gaps and islands problem to the original question. This can be solved with two `row_number()`s in a subquery like so:

```
select seqno, name, towncd
  , Counttown_cd = case 
      when row_number() over (partition by name,towncd,grp order by seqno) = 1 
        then count(*) over (partition by name,towncd, grp) 
      else null 
      end
from (
  select *
    , grp = row_number() over (partition by name,towncd order by seqno) 
          - row_number() over (order by seqno)
  from temp
    ) t
order by seqno
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/VGXI71945

returns:

```
+-------+------+--------+--------------+
| seqno | name | towncd | Counttown_cd |
+-------+------+--------+--------------+
|     1 | man  |   0001 | 2            |
|     2 | man  |   0001 | NULL         |
|     3 | test |   0003 | 1            |
|     4 | man  |   0001 | 2            |
|     5 | man  |   0001 | NULL         |
+-------+------+--------+--------------+
```

---

Answer to the original question:

Using a `case` expression and two window functions (`row_number()` and `count(*) over()`) to only display the count for the first instance of `name,towncd`:

```
select seqno, name, towncd
  , Counttown_cd = case 
      when row_number() over (partition by name,towncd order by seqno) = 1 
        then count(*) over (partition by name,towncd) 
      else null 
      end
from temp
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NZSPR13395

returns:

```
+-------+------+--------+--------------+
| seqno | name | towncd | Counttown_cd |
+-------+------+--------+--------------+
|     1 | man  |   0001 | 2            |
|     2 | man  |   0001 | NULL         |
|     3 | test |   0003 | 1            |
+-------+------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: @etsa Not if the desired results are correct for `seqno = 3`. In the desired results  `counttown_cd` was `1` for `seqno = 3`. If  `counttown_cd` should be `2` for `seqno = 3`, then use `sum()` instead of `count()`.